# Emacs weird region-killing

Tags: emacs

emacs behaves a bit weird when killing regions with 'kill-region, i.e. it kills the region even if it's not really selected. it remembers somehow where the last selection was and if nothing is selected at the moment it kills previously remembered region.

that's really confusing because accidental C-w (with no selection) cuts something that I definitely don't want to be cut.

is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Just FYI, the reason this works like that is that Emacs predates fancy terminals capable of highlighting a selected region.  You just had the cursor position (what Emacs calls "point") and an invisible "mark" that together formed the current region.  Highlighting that region (and deactivating it after certain actions) is a fairly new feature in Emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remap `C-w` to work only when selected region currently exists:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-w")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (when mark-active
      (call-interactively 'kill-region))))
```